# NumberFormat for currency returns differnet values for same locale on different android versions

Tags: android, locale, currency-formatting

Im formatting my currency on "es Colombia" and "es Mexico" locales, sometimes I need one and sometimes I need the other one.

The issue is that the format returns different values based on android versions.

Im getting the locale in two different ways:

```
// Option 1
val locale = Locale("es_CO")

// Option 2
val locale = Locale.getAvailableLocales().firstOrNull {
    it.language == "es" && it.displayCountry.compareTo("Colombia", true) == 0
}
```

And Then I format it like:

```
val formatter = DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).apply {
    minimumFractionDigits = 0
    maximumFractionDigits = 0
}


// On Android 28
formatter.format(1000000) ->  "$ 1.000.000"

// On Android 17
formatter.format(1000000) ->  "1.000.000 $"
```

Im also checking if the `formatter.currency` is changing but it is the same for both android versions.

Why is that?

Comment: It could be that for Android 17, the system does not have _correct_ data about how to format currencies for certain locale. A lot of things are added in every new android version. Also, these formats evolve over the years as well. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#lai

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it manually but it still feels like it is not the right solution, but it works on multiple android versions:

```
    val formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale)

    (formatter as? DecimalFormat)?.apply {
        val cleanPattern = toPattern().replace("¤", "").trim()
        applyPattern("¤ $cleanPattern")
    }

    // Use formatter
```